# R insert vector into vector

Tags: r, vector

I have the vector `v1 = c(a, b, c, d, e, f)` and, on the other hand, the vector `v2 = c(1,2,3,4)`.

**My Requirement:**

I want to insert vector `v2` into vector `v1` after position 1, each value of `v2` overwriting values of `v1`, finally getting a vector `v3 = c(a,1,2,3,4,f)`.

How could I manage it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

We can do an assignment based on position

```
v1[2:(length(v1)-1)] <- v2
v1
#[1] "a" "1" "2" "3" "4" "f"
```

Or the assignment can be based on the length 'v2' by creating a function

```
fnInsert <- function(vec1, vec2, ind){
   
   stopifnot(length(vec1) > length(vec2))
   i1 <- seq(ind, length.out = length(vec2), by = 1)
   replace(vec1, i1, vec2)
}

fnInsert(v1, v2, 2)
#[1] "a" "1" "2" "3" "4" "f"

fnInsert(v1, v2, 3)
#[1] "a" "b" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

It may be better to have some additional checks for edge cases where the length of v2 is greater than v1

```
fnInsert(v1, 1:8, 2)
```

> Error: length(vec1) > length(vec2) is not TRUE

#### data

```
v1 <- letters[1:6]
v2 <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, akrun!